# Does a photon have a north and south pole?

Tags: electromagnetism

A photon has an oscillating magnetic and electric field.

Is the magnetic field a dipole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A photon is not the source of an oscillating magnetic and electric field, and it does not have poles. Your confusion stems from the fact that photons can be seen as field quanta for electromagnetic fields. In a sense they are the field, but they do not create it.

Comment: I knew that you'd answer this question as soon as I saw the title